# Entries from hardcoded category

Tags: categories

Should be easy i thought. How can i display all entries from a section from a certain category?

This is my code now, but nothing shows up (screenshot bottomleft):

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('b2c').first() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('homeBlocks').relatedTo(category).find() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
    {% for cat in entry.businessSegment %}
        {{ cat }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This code shows all entries (screenshot topleft), and you can see there are entries with b2c:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('b2c').first() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('homeBlocks').find() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
    {% for cat in entry.businessSegment %}
        {{ cat }} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[image: screen shot]

My Category Group is called Business Category (with handle "*businessCategory*"). It contains two categories:

- b2c (slug "*b2c*")
- b2b (slug "*b2b*")

The field handle used in the section "*homeBlocks*" is "*businessSegment*"

Where's the error? :)

Comment: What happens if you take the `find()` off of your `relatedTo`? So it becomes: 
`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('homeBlocks').relatedTo(category) %}`

Comment: @damon same result: no entries

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to get. I've updated my answer - see if that gets you closer to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. I'm not 100% sure I've got my site set up the same, but I think it's close.

I have a category group called `Categories`. It looks like this:

```
Categories
    b2a    
    b2b
    b2c
```

I created a section called `homeBlocks` which is a channel (shouldn't matter).
Then on my entry, I have a Categories field with a handle of `categoryOne`.

On my template:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('b2c') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('homeBlocks').relatedTo(category).find() %}

{% if entries | length %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {# No entries found. #}
{% endif %}
```

I have created 3 entries within my `homeBlocks` channel, and I've assigned the 1st entry and the 3rd entry to b2c.

Now I am seeing this when I view the page:

```
<p>Entry Three</p>
<p>Entry One</p>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry for the bad info - I think I understand what you are looking for now. I've updated my answer so give it another try.

Comment: Thanks Damon. Tried it but It shows all entries like my second code example... but i only want the entries with category slug "b2c". So i guess in your example without "Entry Two b2c Business Segment"